# File system and API that supports unlimited nesting of directories?

Tags: file-io, operating-system

I have a project where I have a large set of trees of data. I would absolutely love to do this in the file system, but the trees will likely get VERY deep. Many file systems claim no limit on nesting of directories within each other, but have limits on path length, which puts a limit on the amount of directory nesting. Then from there, there are the APIs/drivers for the file system within an operating system which it seems sometimes put tighter constraints on things. So, my question is, do you know of a system setup (filesystem + operating system + API/library/language) which can support virtually infinite nesting? I can't easily put a bound on the amount of nesting that might arise but I'd say it would often get into the hundreds and in the lifetime of the software may reach the hundreds of thousands for certain branches. (And since I'm not psychic, I'd like it to be able to support beyond that.) The actual size of the data isn't a major concern and is well within the limits of every modern filesystem. It's just the nesting that is pushing the limit.

I'm aware of other ways to achieve this but they all feel less elegant since so many of the things I want are supported by the file system. Storing files, user access control (with the same users acknowledged by the OS), absolute and relative addressing, mounting/symlinking to subtrees, etc. Also, a lot of tools that operate on the file system level would be very useful here.

Comment: I think you'll have to change anyway. Filesystems just aren't designed  to work this way. This seems like the kind of problem made to use a full fledged, powerful database.

Comment: Yes, the database is the fallback if nothing comes of this search. Basically if I do this using a database I end up spending a lot of time making the database act like a file system.

Comment: I can think of one thing that (might) save you: mountable file system images on linux. Have the first (say) 10,000 levels of nesting in the host file system. At each of the 10,000th level directories, have a file that is it's own filesystem image containing the next 10,000 levels. Mount it at the folder in the real filesystem. This will overcome any hard limits on directory nesting at the fs level, but you'll still probably run into both driver and path length problems.

Comment: There needs to be some sort of cap or you can use the file system to mount a denial of service attack by passing say a 2 gigabyte path.

Comment: @Linuxios - Yes I was thinking something along those lines. I'm not all that sure that it'll work but I guess I can give it a shot.

Comment: @RaymondChen That assumes I allow users to directly type the absolute path; I don't plan to. Upon loading the system, a user receives a (cached) subset of the leaves of the tree. The only input they provide is relative to their current locations so it's reasonable to bound that to a much lower number per-request. However, I neither said that this is a public facing system nor that it's a system with anonymous or untrusted users. It's a closed system with few users so if I looked at the logs I'd know the DOS attacker by name. I'd probably know their favorite song and met their mother too.

Comment: But a general purpose operating system doesn't know that. It must protect against applications which do potentially bad things. For something like this it would have to be a special purpose operating system.

Comment: @RaymondChen I know. Whether you want to call the purpose general or special isn't relevant to this question though. The reason I'm here asking if such a system exists is that I'm aware that it's not typically supported. While users/implementers traditionally use file systems a certain way, all a file system is is something that facilitates storing and retrieving data based around a unit called a "file". There is very little about it that must be the way it typically is. So, yes, I am asking for a certain kind of special purpose file system which has a philosophy of deeper classifications.